# Question about preserving cross ratios in projective geometry

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

> Let $ABCDEF$ be a cyclic hexagon, such that $AF,BE,CD$ concur. Prove that $(F,D;E,C)=(A,C;B,D)$.

I'm relatively new to projective geometry. This problem would be solved by perspectivity through the point $AF\cap BE\cap CD$, but I'm not sure you can do that, since the intersection point doesn't necessarily lie on the circle?
[image]

Comment: I have a question that is probably dumb. How do you take the cross ratio of four points that aren't collinear? I thought that was part of the deal...

Comment: you use the Euclidean distances between the points, and plug them into the usual fractions.

Comment: I finally found something about cross-ratios of concyclic points.